# Error "Identifier of an instance was altered" while JPA Fetch and Insert same rows as new rows in db with new ids

Tags: jpa, spring-batch

I need to extract rows from a table make some changes and then insert them back as new rows in same table. I am getting Error Identifier of an instance was altered. Here is my code.

```
List<OrderInfo> orderinfo = ordeRepository.findByOrderId(fetchOrderId);
        orderinfo.stream()
        .forEach(oi -> {
            oi.setOrderId(newOrderId);
            oi.setId(null);
        });
orderInfoRepository.saveAll(orderinfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

when you find orderinfo by repository ,the state of these entities change to managed and when you change any properties of that entity the persistenceContext will track the changes,and make the changes to that entity,but you are changing the id which persistenceContext and the database knows each entity by that,so if you want create new records you can do like this and let the framework give them new ids:

```
   newOrderIdList<OrderInfo> orderinfo = ordeRepository.findByOrderId(fetchOrderId);
       List<OrderInfo> newRecords = orderinfo.stream()
                .map(o->new OrOrderInfo(newOrderId,o.whatevr)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        orderInfoRepository.saveAll(newRecords);
```